# Select to which ItemGroup to add Content entries using .csproj extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, visual-studio-2022, csproj, itemgroup

How could I select to which `ItemGroup` the `Content` entries get added. I am using  [the](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucasazzola.vscode-csproj) .csproj extension in VS Code.

E.g. if I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then there are two options:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="folder\foo.extension" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="folder\foo.extension" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I would like to control which option is used. My ultimate goal is to have the same behavior in `VS Code` as it is in `VS 2022`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which ItemGroup you select, neither does the order.

Usage of **Item**, **ItemGroup** elemtens

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes-and-elements

Posible values for **Content**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#content

Works fine with **dotnet cli** (VS Code)

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="folder/foo.extension">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```